# Codeigniter - passing multiple values to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, view, controller

Okay, so generally I wouldn't have a problem doing this and it would be fairly straight forward, but not so much this time.

Here is the relevant code in my controller:

```
// In order to properly build the form url, we need to include the
                // category and product to the view
                $this->data = array(
                        'category' => $category,
                        'product' => $product
                        );

                // Load the product model and get editable values from the database
                $this->load->model('productadmin/products_model');
                $productInformation = $this->products_model->get_product_data($product);

                // Modular code! Use variable-variables to prevent having to write multiple lines of code
                // when we start returning more information from the data
                foreach ( $productInformation as $variable => $value )
                {
                    $this->data[$variable] = $value;
                }
```

Now, ideally, I should be able to access $product, $category and any variables returned from the products model. Doing a print_r, I get the following:

```
Array ( [category] => 1 [product] => 1 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [product_name] => Duff ) )
```

Notice how what was generated by the foreach statement is contained in it's own array. The easiest solution, would be to know how to access that second array from the view, just by passing `$this->data`.

If that's not do-able, what can I change that would assign the model's associative values inside the data array without creating another array inside of it?

The model simply returns key, value pairs from a get_where statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an associative array for your data before it is passed to the view. Try changing this lines:

```
foreach ( $productInformation as $variable => $value )
{
  $this->data[$variable] = $value;
}
```

with this:

```
foreach ( $productInformation as $variable => $value )
{
  $this->data['product_information'][$variable] = $value;
}
```

And then in your view you can access your product information using `$product_information` variable.

Note: I am assuming that you're passing your data to the view using:

```
$this->load->view('your_view', $this->data);
```

Comment: This actually isn't working for me. Creates the following array: 
Array ( [category] => 1 [product] => 1 [product_information] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [product_name] => Duff ) ) )
Which makes it inaccessable via $product_information['product_name'];

Comment: You can access it via $product_information[0]['product_name'] or you can foreach the array: foreach($product_information as $pi) { echo $pi['product_name']; }