# Codeigniter - passing multiple value to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to build a month report with Codeigniter.
i have problem in parse value to view,
when i enable profiler, i get 12 month query

Controller

```
$this->load->model('dash_model');
$data1= $this->dash_model->get_user_all();
$ind = $this->dash_model->monthreport();
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

$data = array(
          'mont' => $ind,
          'blok' => $data1
        );
 print_r($data);
 $this->parser->parse('blank', $data);
```

the output print_r data

```
Array
(
[mont] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [trans_email] => 0
            )

    )
```

and dash_model

```
for($i=1; $i<=12;)
    {
     $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    $m = $month[$i];
    $query2=$this->db->query("select count(*) as trans_email from trans_email where lup LIKE '2014-$m%' ");
        $i++;

    }
    return $query2->result();
```

how i get output select count(*) as trans_email from trans_email where lup LIKE '2014-01%' and next month to view ?
like
 month 1 = 356 data
 month 2 = 2000 data and next

i'm trying this : [Codeigniter - passing multiple values to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905942/codeigniter-passing-multiple-values-to-view) 
but nothing happens

update
i'm trying to add this code into dash_model

```
  $i++;
              $resultarray[$i]=$query2->result();
    }
    return $resultarray;
```

and i got some error

> *** Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string***

Comment: __....the question__

Comment: the question is ????

Comment: Please explain it clearly it not understanding

Comment: you asked what you were missing.... what you are missing is the question....

Comment: no, question is how i get output select count(*) as trans_email from trans_email where lup LIKE '2014-01%' and next month to view.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay dude let me try to guest :D
let's assume you use array on your view, i can assume that because you initialize $data with array.

First make sure you read this [userguide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)
on result_array() section.

then change `$query->result();` to `$query->result_array();`

then try to var_dump() it, hope it's work

Answer (score 0):

just pass it as

```
$data['mont'] = $ind;
$data['blok'] = $data1;
$this->parser->parse('blank', $data);
```

in the view get the data as of `$ind` as `$mont`
and `$data1` as `$blok`.

Answer (score -2):

You could do

`$data = array();
$data['mont'] = $ind;
$data['blok'] = $data1;`

Instead of declaring it then initializing it at the same time. (It also allow you to add/change data in it whenever you want in your controller).

Then do `debug($data);`to see if you got everything you want in `$data`.

Comment: Well actually, it may be the answer, if it's NULL, it's why the array doesn't have 2 cell.

Comment: $data1 output  [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [r1] => 2
                    [r2] => 0
                    [r3] => 0
                    [r4] => 0
                    [r5] => 0
                    [r6] => 0

Comment: Updated it for answering.

Comment: @Sorikairo output remains same when i change to $data[]

Comment: @user3123347 Have you tried to only create a $data with a 'blok' cell, then ouput $data ?